# Hunting down Missing Web Parts

Tags: 2010

We recently ran test-spcontentdatabase a Sharepoint 2010 farm and got a list of missing features and web parts, etc. I've been busy hunting down all the erroring web parts on various pages and removing them either by deleting straight off the page or by appending ?contents=1 to the URL and deleting the closed ErrorWeParts that way.

I've been finding the pages with an SQL query against the content database mentioned in the errors. However, for a few I just can't seem to find the problem. There's nothing wrong with the page and no closed web parts show up as errors.

These are not publishing sites or pages with versioning, so I don't think it's old versions of files. One thought I have is whether these reported errors that still show up in the SQL query are on personalized views of the page. But I have no idea how to find that. And it's one of those crazy ideas anyway.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
select d.dirname
    , d.LeafName 
    , wp.tp_ZoneID
from alldocs d with (nolock)
inner join AllWebParts wp with (nolock) on d.id = wp.tp_PageUrlID
where wp.tp_WebPartTypeId = @currentGuid
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to detach the Content DB and re attach it.

did you try the Code Plex solutions?
here are these:

[SharePoint Feature Administration and Clean Up Tool](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/)

[SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/)

I would recomend this blog, mentioned almost every option:
http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/08/fix-features-missing-issue-in-migration.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. As I work through my issue list I'll definitely be looking over these utilities. I'll mark this as the answer as it's the most definite way I've seen of cleaning up these errors.